# Output of algorithm in R not stored in variable

Tags: r

I'm using a "caesar" package which can be found at [pdf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caesar/caesar.pdf). As part of my code, I need to store the output of the Caesar algorithm in a variable to change it to binary form. For some reasons I can't store the output in a variable. I started  by `typeof()` then `unlist`. nothing works. 
 here is the command used for encryption :

```
caesar("15", direction = "left", distance = 2, reverse = FALSE)
```

where, "15" is the message to be encrypted.

- using `typeof()` : `typeof(caesar("15", direction = "left", distance = 2, reverse = FALSE))` . returns : `37[1] "NULL"`
- using `unlist()` : `unlist(caesar("15", direction = "left", distance = 2, reverse = FALSE), use.names = FALSE)` . returns: `34NULL`

I even tried to create c().

```
x<-c(caesar("15", direction = "left", distance = 2, reverse = FALSE))
>37
> x
>NULL
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Why would you wrap `c()` around a function call? (But voting to close as not having a reproducible example for  a Q about unexpected results.) Do note: "it didn't work" is one of those phrases that triggers an allergic reaction in many readers of this forum and others that encourage questions. Do learn to specify what was expected and what was seen and why the results did not met expectations.

Comment: Did you try just `x <- caesar("15")` and see if it works?

Comment: @42- I was trying everything (I know) because the package manual doesn’t include much about the output type and I guess that’s the point of asking questions. Please note Since my question about the return type, I gave all the example I have done especially we are talking about one command. If you try the package, you would get the full picture. BTW , “didn’t work “ for me as I was referring to the command used. However, I’m going to update it . Thanks for your helpful comment .

Comment: @thelatemail yes I tried , I didn’t store the value in the variable .

Comment: Looks like the function is not written to output data properly - the last line of `caesar` is `cat(text)` which returns the string to the screen only, rather than as an object/string that can be saved. I'd file a bug report with the author. If you're desperate to use it now, take a copy of the function `tmpcaes <- caesar` and `fix(tmpcaes)`, change the last line to `text` and then run `tmpcaes` instead.

Comment: @thelatemail thank you very much. I will do you your recommendation.

Comment: If you had written something close to ... "The help page for `caesar` says the value of the  function is a string, but assigning the value of that function doesn't return a string", ... then it would have been clear. The difficulty is either in the documentation or in the function, so I do agree with thelatemail that you should communicate with the package author. He has definitely  incorrectly described the behavior of his code and it quite possible that he will change the code to match the apparent intent..

Comment: No issue/bug-report required: the last line of the function (posted 23 days ago) is [`return(text)`](https://github.com/jacobkap/caesar/blob/master/R/caesar.R#L84) (though I usually find the use of `cat` in a function like this unnecessary at best). I suggest you install the github version with something like `devtools::install_github("jacobkap/caesar")` and try again.

Comment: ... but as a temporary workaround, you could do `x <- capture.output(caesar("15", ...))` (with all of your arguments). This is most definitely a ***hack***/workaround, not to be taken as a long-term solution to anything. (And it will probably fail in rmarkdown rendering.)

Comment: @42- yes , the code is incorrectly described in the manual. Will contact the package author. Thank you.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for your comment. I will install the github version and give it a try. I like the **hack** (smart workaround).

Comment: Please don't use the word "smart" with that hack ;-) ... I'm a little embarrassed to suggest it, but thought it might be useful as an emergency workaround when "The Right Solution (tm)" is not immediately tenable.

Comment: @r2evans It adds something new for me( worth to be voted as useful comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot store the output of the caesar function because the function itself is not returning a variable. Looking into the code of the function you will find

```
...        
cat(text)
...
```

The function is not storing the variable "text" anywhere, it is just printing it on the screen.
If you want to store it somewhere you have to change the body of the function so it can actually return the variable called text.

Try this:

```
caesar_new<-function (text, direction = "left", distance = 3, reverse = FALSE) 
{
if (!is.character(text)) {
stop("text must be a string!")
 }
if (!is.numeric(distance)) {
stop("distance must be a number!")
}
if (!distance %in% -46:46) {
stop("distance must be between -46 and 46")
} 
direction <- tolower(direction)
if (!direction %in% c("left", "right")) {
stop("direction must be 'left' or 'right'")
}
alphabet <- data.frame(original = letters, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
special <- data.frame(original = c(0:9, " ", "!", ",", "@", 
                                 "&", "%", "-", "_", ":", ";", "?", "'"))
alphabet <- rbind(alphabet, special)
alphabet$cipher <- binhf::shift(alphabet$original, places = distance, 
                              dir = direction)
alphabet <- rbind(alphabet, data.frame(original = c("#", 
                                                  "\n"), cipher = c("#", "\n")))
if (!reverse) {
text <- tolower(text)
text <- gsub("[^[:alnum:][:space:]',!@&%-_:;]", "", 
             text)
text <- gsub("\\.", "", text)
text <- gsub(" +", " ", text)
for (i in 1:nchar(text)) {
  index_num <- which(substr(text, i, i) == alphabet$original)
  substr(text, i, i) <- alphabet$cipher[index_num]
}
}
else {
text <- gsub(" +", " ", text)
for (i in 1:nchar(text)) {
  index_num <- which(substr(text, i, i) == alphabet$cipher)
  substr(text, i, i) <- alphabet$original[index_num]
}
}
text <- gsub("\\\n", "\n#", text)
text <- gsub("#+", "#", text)
return(text)
}



x<-caesar_new("15", direction = "left", distance = 2, reverse = FALSE)


x
[1] "37"
```

In doing this you are actually changing the body of the function so it can store the variable you're interested in. You can also cast it to a different data type if you'd like to.

Comment: Thank you. it works. I will take this as a temporary solution until the author updates the package.

Comment: The last CRAN release for that package was two years ago. There are no indications of high volume work by the author (not a criticism), so you might want to reach out (raise their first [issue](https://github.com/jacobkap/caesar/issues) or perhaps [email](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caesar/index.html)) to ask if this change will be submitted to CRAN any time soon. Lacking that, it would be far safer for you to `devtools::install_github` so that you have a portable solution and the complete package available. (Just my two cents :-)